# Custom properties for Custom ExtJs components

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have few ExtJS components extended (Window,DataView etc) using Ext.extend method. I would like to add few additional properties to the extended. How do I add these into my component?

```
ExWindow = Ext.extend(Ext.Window,{
border:false,
initComponent: function() {     

    // Component Configuration...   
    var config = {
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'simplepanel'
        }]
    };  

    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
    ExWindow.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);       

},
onRender:function() { 
   ExWindow.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
}
});
```

Comment: There is no need to include an override of onRender unless you're going to include some code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ExWindow = Ext.extend(Ext.Window,{
border:false,
newPublicProperty: 0,
newPublicArray: new Array(),
initComponent: function() {     

    // Component Configuration...   
    var config = {
        height: 500,
        width: 500,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'simplepanel'
        }]
    };  

    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));
    ExWindow.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);       

},
onRender:function() { 
   ExWindow.superclass.onRender.apply(this, arguments);
},
newPublicMethod:function() {
}
});
```

newPublicProperty, newPublicArray, newPublicMethod - new additional properties of object.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not able to access the property or the method.. I get win.newPublicMethod is not a function in firebug!

Comment: var win = new ExWindow(); win.newPublicMethod(); But if you want add new property to the Ext.Window - this is other question.

Comment: here is what is do: var win = new ExWindow(); alert(win.newPublicProperty); -> but it says undefined!!!

Comment: You probably don't want to add the array property in this manner. Doing so means that every instance of the class shares the same array reference, and if it changes for one object all objects will see the change. It's better to declare the property null (for readability) then initialize the array within the initComponent method.